# How to find shortest path in a equal weighted graph

Tags: shortest-path

I have a graph which looks like this:
All the edges between nodes have distance = 1.

```
      F
      |
      E
      |
A-B-C-D
|     |
G     O
|     |
H     P
|     |
I     Q
|     |
J     R
|     |
K-L-M-N
```

I have to find the shortest path from A node to Q.
The algorithm which i use is as follows(borrowed from wikipedia):

```
 1 function Dijkstra(Graph, source):
 2
 3      create vertex set Q
 4
 5      for each vertex v in Graph:             // Initialization
 6          dist[v] ← INFINITY                  // Unknown distance from source to v
 7          prev[v] ← UNDEFINED                 // Previous node in optimal path from source
 8          add v to Q                          // All nodes initially in Q (unvisited nodes)
 9
10      dist[source] ← 0                        // Distance from source to source
11      
12      while Q is not empty:
13          u ← vertex in Q with min dist[u]    // Source node will be selected first
14          remove u from Q 
15          
16          for each neighbor v of u:           // where v is still in Q.
17              alt ← dist[u] + length(u, v)
18              if alt < dist[v]:               // A shorter path to v has been found
19                  dist[v] ← alt 
20                  prev[v] ← u 
21
22      return dist[], prev[]
```

The main problem when i use djikstra's algo is that i am not able to get the shortest path to traverse from source to destination.
Algorithm traverses across nodes which are not in the shortest path,to find the shortest path.

```
E.g if i traverse from A->Q i traverse through other nodes like(G->H->I..)
But the path from G->H->I does not lead to the destination.
But the path from A->B->C... leads to the shortest path.
```

How do i backtrace the correct path?

Answer (score 0):

That is what the prev array in djikstra's algorithm is for

You know the destination is Q, so prev[Q] is the node right before Q in the optimal path (which in this case is P)

prev[P] is O, prev[O] is D, and so on until you get to A which is the origin of the path.